# Yodlee exception - cipher is bad

Tags: yodlee

When using the Yodlee API we're getting some internal exception:

`CoreExceptionFaultMessage::com.yodlee.core.InternalCoreException: Cipher is bad: no such key: ... in keyring: itemsummary|...CipherText: ... | MemId=... | Container Type: credits |ItemId=... while invoking Yodlee DataService`

How can we fix this? Is this a problem on our end or at Yodlee's end?

Answer (score 0):

David,

Apologies for the delay in responding. We have resolved the issue, could you please confirm the same.

-Vijay

David,

This is Vijay from Yodlee and I manage the support for our Yodlee Interactive customers. We have identified the root cause for the issue (Cipher is Bad) and working on fixing it, you will hear shortly from us on this.

-Vijay

Answer (score -1):

David... It looks like while returning account number for this user(encrypted) the system at Yodlee may be failing. It seems like a bug.

Please raise a Service request with user, item-id info and full XML request and response to investigate further.

Comment: Prashant... This happens to a *lot* of users. Sounds like a nasty bug. Do I really need to send the XML? We're doing nothing different than usual.

Comment: This happens to me as well, it's really annoying... please fix it ASAP!

Comment: Dave... XML responses or a stack trace would help our developer identify exactly where it fails, so yes it would be best if you raise a service request with that information. It will also avoid some back-forth between the support teams and you. You can send us the SR# via email to our customer care team and we will get this checked on priority for sure.

Comment: David, Michael - not sure if you guys have access to the YCC tool which is used by current customers. If you can send more details on which user, item-id, etc that will help the team track down the root cause. You can post that to us via our contact form if you are not on YCC:  http://solutions.yodlee.com/web-inquiry.html and just note that you were forwarded there by Grace on stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: I added a YCC request. I hope this gets solved quickly. Usually the YCC platform is not responsive.

Comment: David... Please send me the SR# separately.